# Cut a jpg file in C, (NOT crop)

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

i would like to know how can i cut a jpg file using a coordinates i want to retrieve using artoolkit and opencv, see:

[Blob Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366421/blob-detection-in-c/10436211#10436211)

i want to retrieve coordinates of the white sheet and then use those coordinates to cut a jpg file I'm took before.
Find this but how can this help?
[How to slice/cut an image into pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875372/how-to-slice-cut-an-image-into-pieces)

Comment: Add the C tag to your question since you are looking for C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the coordinates, you might want to [deskew the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800905/affine-transform-simple-rotation-and-scaling-or-something-else-entirely) first:

http://nuigroup.com/?ACT=28&fid=27&aid=1892_H6eNAaign4Mrnn30Au8d

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint) uses `cv::warpPerspective()` to achieve that effect.

The references above use the **C++** interface of OpenCV, but I'm sure you are capable of converting between the two.

Second, *cutting* a particular area of an image is known as extracting a Region Of Interest (ROI). The general procedure is: create a `CvRect` to define your ROI and then call `cvSetImageROI()` followed by `cvSaveImage()` to save it on the disk.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10326191/176769) shares **C** code to achieve this task.

Comment: uhm ok i will try to look at the post and see want i can do thanks again Karl

Comment: Karl i was seeing the deskew image but its not what i want i just want to cut the image using the coordinates so i can use it as an opengl texture i think if i deskew the image i will not have the perfect match for my texture (its is just what i thing not sure of that)

Comment: The last reference I shared provides the code, which among other things, sets a ROI and save it to the disk.